# LaTeX code with input dependent on some integer parameters

Tags: input, loops, external-files, programming, automation

Suppose that I have a large number of `.tex` files with names `1.tex`, `2.tex`, `...`, `N.tex` (with `N` = some integer).

I would like to write a LaTeX document, where I set some parameters for example:

```
howMany = 10, from = 21
```

and then, when I compile this file I obtain the pdf output which contains the contents of the input files `21.tex`, `22.tex`, `...`, `30.tex`. If `howMany > N` or `from + howMany > N` I would like to show some error message in the pdf output.

Is it possible to do it in LaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is! I defined a command `\MultiInput[<ini>]{<num>}{<name template>}` which loops from `<ini>` (default is `1`) to `<ini>+<num>-1`, replaces the `#1` in `<name template>` by the current number and checks if the file exists. If it does the file is input, otherwise it prints `!ERROR!` to the PDF file and shows an error message in the console.

The code below produces:

> [image]

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file_1.tex}
Hello
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file_2.tex}
World
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \MultiInput { O{1} m m }
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnn {#1} {#1+#2-1}
      {
        \file_if_exist:nTF {#3}
          { \input {#3} }
          {
            !ERROR!
            \msg_error:nnn { azonips } { file-not-found } {#3}
          }
      }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { azonips } { file-not-found }
  { File~`#1'~not~found. }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\MultiInput{1}{file_#1.tex}

\MultiInput{2}{file_#1.tex}

\MultiInput{3}{file_#1.tex}

\MultiInput[2]{1}{file_#1.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for answer. I have additional question: Is it possible to compute reminder of n divided by k in LaTeX (to avoid checking is the file exists)?

Comment: @azonips Yes, it is. You can use `\int_mod:nn{n}{k}` in the code above. However I don't know how this could replace checking if the file exists... If you explain what you have in mind I can change the code for you.

Comment: I would like to have input files from one with name: (from mod N) + 1, to one with name ((from + howMany) mod N) + 1, then I get as filename i.tex, where i is an integer from 1 to N.

Comment: @azonips I'm still not sure of what you are trying to accomplish, sorry. However, try replacing the line `\int_step_inline:nnn {#1} {#1+#2-1}` by this: `\int_step_inline:nnn { \int_mod:nn {#1} {3} +1 } { \int_mod:nn {#1+#2} {3} +1 }` and see if it helps.

Comment: Where can I read sth about `\int_step_inline` instruction? I understand that #1, #2, #3 are arguments of `\MultiInput` function. If `\int_step_inline` is sth similar to `for(int i;i<n;i++) {}` I would like to do sth with `i` (which is, in general, not #1, #2 or #3). Is it possible to obtain sth like `i` from `\int_step_inline` instruction?

Comment: I write some code in C++ to explain what I would like to do: `for (int i=from;i<from+howMany;i++) input(i%howMany + 1);` (asuuming that function input is defined elsewhere)

Comment: @azonips Okay, I completely misunderstood what you want. Something like this: https://pastebin.com/25cGkU9B? The function computes `\int_mod:nn{#1}{howMany}+1` by itself and replaces in the file name template. However now you have to use `##1` instead of `#1` in the template. Yes, `\int_step_inline:nnn{a}{b}{<code>}` loops from `a` to `b` and executes `<code>` each time. Within `<code>`, `#1` is the loop variable (`i` in the C++ code). You can learn more about it [here](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#page=94).

Comment: code from link realize, after small changes and simplifications, what I wanted to do. Thank you for help!

Comment: @azonips You're welcome :-) If you have any further problems, feel free to start a new question! Just a note for future questions: Always try to say _exactly_ what you want to do, so that the answer solves your problem right away, instead of requiring further clarifications in the comments.